# SyntaxError with template string literal on iOS safari

Tags: javascript, string, safari, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am having a problem with template string literals. The code works flawlessly on Chrome, Firefox, Edge but fails to execute on Safari.

[image]

This is my interpolate string extension I use to interpolate external HTML templates.

[image]

And this is the babel-compiled code that fails to execute correctly

[image]

Is there any working polyfill that could solve this error on Safari browser? Or a way to rewrite this interpolate string extension to work with plain old string literal?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.

Apparently fat arrow functions **song => { ... }** were not transpiled when imported from html template using html-loader. Changed it to good old **function(song) { return... }** style syntax and it works. Ugly but working. Hope to find a way to transpile es6 from html templates too.

```
<!--${songs.map(song => `-->
${songs.map(function(song) { return `
<div data-menuanchor="${song.anchor}" class="node song">
    <div class="label">${song.number}</div>
    <div class="timer"></div>
    <div class="line">
        <div class="lineProgress"></div>
        <div class="lineDefault"></div>
    </div>
    <a href="#${song.anchor}" class="link">
        <div class="linkDefault"></div>
        <div class="linkHover"></div>
        <div class="linkBass rythm-medium"></div>
    </a>
    <div class="actions">
        <div class="playBtn"><i class="icon bg-play"></i></div>
        <div class="pauseBtn"><i class="icon bg-pause"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>
`}).join('')}
<!--`).join('')}-->
```